# LINQ Query append additional Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that takes in two Lists. Below is how I am trying to use those two lists within the query but it only works if I have one list. If I have data in both lists I get an empty data set returned even though if I have one list with the same data it works.

```
            var query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Items>().AsQueryable();

            if(itemIds?.Any() == true)
                query = query.Where(item=> itemIds.Contains(item.PartitionKey));
            if (itemSNs?.Any() == true)
                query = query.Where(item=> itemSNs.Contains(item.itemInfo.SN));
```

How would I go about appending the additional query onto it if I have both lists populated?

Comment: Your described behavior of what the code does doesn't match the code's intent, which should do what you expect it to do. Can you please draft a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) to confirm that the source of the issue is in fact located in the posted code? Because I suspect it's somewhere else that you haven't shown.

Comment: This way is fine, but you are applying the two `Where` clauses with an "and". Were you expecting them to be "or" together

Comment: Change the if to have an other layer to catch both and use an Or `||`. Or concat both List

Comment: Probably not the issue, but just in case can you try `_container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Items>().AsQueryable().toList()`?

Comment: @Flater Sorry if you already know this, but typing `[mre]` in a comment will give you [mre].

Comment: @gunr2171: Sweet! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need Or not And

```
if(itemIds?.Any() == true && itemSNs?.Any() == true)
          query = query.Where(item=> itemIds.Contains(item.PartitionKey) || 
                         itemSNs.Contains(item.itemInfo.SN));
 else if(itemIds?.Any() == true)
            query = query.Where(item=> itemIds.Contains(item.PartitionKey));
 else if (itemSNs?.Any() == true)
          query = query.Where(item=> itemSNs.Contains(item.itemInfo.SN));
```

Answer (score 0):

One of solution, using LINQKit and it's `PredicateBuilder`:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Items>();
if (itemIds?.Any() == true)
    predicate = predicate.Or(item => itemIds.Contains(item.PartitionKey));
if (itemSNs?.Any() == true)
    predicate = predicate.Or(item => itemSNs.Contains(item.itemInfo.SN));

query = query.Where(predicate);
```